# UIAlertView EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, exc-bad-access, uiactionsheet

I cannot figure out why I keep getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line below in the action sheet method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:numberFinal]];
```

I added my code, but I just don't see why its being over released.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    number = [[results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"phone"];

    number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    numberFinal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",number];
    //tel:1234567890
    NSLog(@"NUMBER:%@",numberFinal);

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UIAlertView *alert2 = [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Call" message:@"Call This Person?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil]autorelease];
    alert2.tag = kAlertViewTwo;

    [alert2 show];
   // [alert2 release];


}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if(actionSheet.tag == kAlertViewOne) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
        }else{
        }
    }
    else if(actionSheet.tag == kAlertViewTwo) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            //ok button clicked - close alert  
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:numberFinal]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do an NSLog before the line and print **numberFinal** to see if it allocated ok.

Make sure your class is a UIAlertView Delegate

Try the same line of code in another function to see if it causes the same issue. It might be because you are accessing sharedApplication from within the UIAlertView click event.

Hope that helps :)